# IntelliJ is not starting the tests, Failed to start: 1, passed: 0

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

I am trying to run my selenium webdriver test in IntelliJ - Maven + testng.
I am using Java 8, IntelliJ 2021 version.

The test was running fine until yesterday.
But suddenly I started getting this error in the IntelliJ event log and test failed to run.

Failed to start: 1, passed: 0

The console output is below:

```
2021-08-24 16:11:41 INFO  logger:27 - Running the test class: org.xx.xx.test_automation.xx.Test
2021-08-24 16:11:41 INFO  logger:93 - The number of test cases to be executed is: 0
2021-08-24 16:11:41 INFO  logger:36 - Finished Test Method
Default Suite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I restarted Intellij, uninstalled and re-installed the intelliJ.
Still the issue persist. 
Can someone please help solve this problem?

[image: Attached the intelli Event log]

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1744774)

Comment: Sample project would be also helpful

Comment: If it changed `The test was running fine until yesterday`... please check your version control what has changed... Also recheck the build on plain command line ....